# How to draw python seaborn histograms in matplotlib subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I've produced two code snippets for seaborn histograms in subplots.
First one

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 5), sharey=False)
sns.histplot(ax=axes[1,0],x=data.age)
sns.histplot(ax=axes[0,0],x=data.duration)
plt.show()
```

which gives me an error:

```
sns.histplot(ax=axes[1,0],x=data.age)
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

and the second one

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 5), sharey=False)
sns.histplot(ax=axes[1],x=data.age)
sns.histplot(ax=axes[0],x=data.duration)
plt.show()
```

which gives me
[image]

The data are from bank marketing dataset from uci.

Pleas advise me what I'm doing wrong in the first snippet.

Comment: You can write `fig, axes = plt.subplots(..., squeeze=False)` to always have axes with 2D indices. The default is `squeeze=True` with 1D indices in case there is  only one row or only one column of axes (or even no indices when there is only one ax). The default permits writing `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)` instead of the unfamiliar looking `fig, ((ax1, ), (ax2, )) = plt.subplots(1, 2, squeeze=False)`. Especially when the number of rows is calculated on-the-fly, `squeeze=False` will be helpful.

Comment: works :) thank you